# Template files and Machine Names

Tags: theming

I am trying to create some variables in my template.php file using the form machine names from a content type I created. Then I am creating a node.tpl.php template file that is related to the content type so I can perform the layout I want. I don't think I have the right syntax. Here it is:

```
$node = $variables['node'];
function keevilcontracting_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

 if($variables['type'] == 'project') {
    kpr($variables);
 $variables['title'] = $node->title;
 $variables['coverPhoto'] = $node->field_cover_photo; // 'field_cover_photo is the machine name of the field in my content type form.
 $variables['projectDesc'] = $node->body;
 $variables['additionalPhotos'] = $node->field_additional_photos;
 }

}
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have that

```
$node = $variables['node'];
```

outside your function.

put it as the first line inside your preprocess function.

$variables doesn't actually exist out there (and if it does it won't be the $variables variable you're expecting in this case).